# I have some difficulties in understanding this XPATH expression/syntax

Tags: xml, xpath

here is the xpath used for selecting nodes.

```
document.SelectNodes("my/node/url/@*[name(.)!='name_excluded']");
```

I can understand the **@*** and the **!=' '**
But I can not grasp the **[name(.) some predicate  ]**

I haven't found reference for (.) at [XPath (w3 org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` in the predicate refers to the current node (it's an [AbbreviatedStep](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-AbbreviatedStep))

[`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) is a function that takes a node-set (here, we pass it the context node) and returns its name

So the missing parts of your understanding are: we're going to return any attribute (`@*`) SUCH THAT the **attribute**'s name is not `name_excluded`.

Answer (score 1):

`@*` selects all the attributes of all the `url` nodes. `name(.)` is then, for each of those attributes, its name, so this selects all attributes of `url` nodes except for the `name_excluded` attributes.